# Public MonoBehavior string fields empty

Tags: unity, c#, .net, monobehaviour

This is bizarre enough that it *has* to be me being an idiot.

I have a `MonoBehaviour` with some public fields and public methods:

```
public class MyComponentA : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string Message = "Foobar";
    public int Integer = 42;

    public string GetMessage() => "This is a message.";
    public int GetInteger() => 42;
}
```

I've added it to a prefab  called `Circle_A`.

`Circle_B` has a `MonoBehavior` that will instantiate an instance of `Circle_A`, get the component and log out the values returned from the fields and the methods:

```
public class CircleB : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _circleAPrefab;

    private void Start()
    {
        var circleAInstance = Instantiate(_circleAPrefab, new Vector2(10, 10), Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.zero),transform);
        var myComponentA = circleAInstance.GetComponent<MyComponentA>();
        var message = myComponentA.Message;
        LogIt(message);
        LogIt(myComponentA.GetMessage());
        LogIt(message);
        Log(myComponentA.Integer);
        Log(myComponentA.GetInteger());
    }

    private static void LogIt(string message)
    {
        switch (message)
        {
            case null:
                Log("NULL");
                return;
            case "":
                Log("EMPTY");
                return;
            default:
                Log($"'{message}'");
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

The integer field and both the methods return as expected, the number `42` and the message`This is a message`.  The message field however is always an empty string.

What's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code, it's working.  Select the prefab with a double click - it is possible that you have emptied the value of Message for the prefab in the Inspector of Circle_A.

Comment: If I had emptied it then I would be getting a `NullReferenceException` when I called the members.

Comment: Now I understand what you're saying and, you're totally right.  The UI was overriding the hard coded values.  Thank you.  I was going mad.